# Spring ComponentScan causing java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I had a semi-working (as in runnable) Spring Boot web app to which I was trying add security. I had a REST service with OAuth2 working but I also needed authentication working on the WebMvc side. I could not get this working in the way I had things so I refactored the config:

```
public class SpringConfigurationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer
{
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses()
    {
        return new Class[] { AppConfiguration.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses()
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings()
    {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"co.sens.rest", "co.sens.data", "co.sens.docdata", "co.sens.aggregators"})
@Import({ WebMvcConfig.class, OAuth2ServerConfig.class, SecurityConfiguration.class, CustomUserDetailsService.class })
public class AppConfiguration {
}
```

So the intention is that this scans for components in the app itself (co.sens.rest) along with external code in referenced jars. The main intention to keep the data access separate.

Since doing this I am now getting the following error which from what I can gather is because Spring Security is kicking in too soon. It is trying to Autowire my UserRepository for my custom UserDetailsService.

Before adding the AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer I could get it to run but I could not get security on the web side to work

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'methodSecurityConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private co.sens.rest.config.SecurityConfiguration co.sens.rest.config.MethodSecurityConfig.securityConfig; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setContentNegotationStrategy(org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationStrategy); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration.setConfigurers(java.util.List); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private co.sens.rest.controllers.UsersController co.sens.rest.controllers.web.WebController.usersController; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usersController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private co.sens.data.Operations co.sens.rest.controllers.UsersController.dataOperations; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'operations': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private co.sens.docdata.DocStoreOperations co.sens.data.Operations.docStoreOperations; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'docStoreOperations': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private co.sens.docdata.repositories.UserRepository co.sens.docdata.DocStoreOperations.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@553a3d88: startup date [Fri Jul 10 08:55:21 BST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:232)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:615)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at co.sens.rest.Application.main(Application.java:11)
```

Full stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/SJLa2pSc

**UPDATE**

Configuration:

```
package co.sens.rest.config;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"co.sens.data", "co.sens.docdata", "co.sens.aggregators"})
public class AppConfiguration {
}

public class MessageSecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

}

@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfig {

    private static final String SENS_RESOURCE_ID = "sens";

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
            resources.resourceId(SENS_RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false); //.authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint()); //.stateless(false);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/api").access("#oauth2.hasScope('read') and hasRole('ROLE_USER')");

        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Autowired
        private UserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler;

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManagerBean")
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Autowired
        private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory().withClient("sensapp")
                    .resourceIds(SENS_RESOURCE_ID)
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token",
                            "password")
                    .authorities("USER")
                    .scopes("read", "write")
                    .secret("secret");
        }

        @Bean
        public TokenStore tokenStore() {
            return new InMemoryTokenStore();
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints
                    .tokenStore(tokenStore)
                    .userApprovalHandler(userApprovalHandler)
                    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        }

        @Bean
        @Primary
        public DefaultTokenServices tokenServices() {
            DefaultTokenServices tokenServices = new DefaultTokenServices();
            tokenServices.setSupportRefreshToken(true);
            tokenServices.setTokenStore(this.tokenStore);
            return tokenServices;
        }
        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer.realm("sens/client");
        }
    }

    protected static class Approvals {

        @Autowired
        private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Bean
        public ApprovalStore approvalStore() throws Exception {
            TokenApprovalStore store = new TokenApprovalStore();
            store.setTokenStore(tokenStore);
            return store;
        }

        @Bean
        @Lazy
        @Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
        public SensUserApprovalHandler userApprovalHandler() throws Exception {
            SensUserApprovalHandler handler = new SensUserApprovalHandler();
            handler.setApprovalStore(approvalStore());
            handler.setRequestFactory(new DefaultOAuth2RequestFactory(clientDetailsService));
            handler.setClientDetailsService(clientDetailsService);
            handler.setUseApprovalStore(true);
            return handler;
        }
    }
}

public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/web/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/login/**", "/resources/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/login").failureUrl("/login?authorization_error=true").defaultSuccessUrl("/web/home").loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
public class ServletInitializer extends AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext createServletApplicationContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.scan(ClassUtils.getPackageName(getClass()));
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected WebApplicationContext createRootApplicationContext() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        DelegatingFilterProxy filter = new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain");
        filter.setContextAttribute("org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcher");
        servletContext.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", filter).addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
    }

}
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    //@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/")
                .setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateResolver defaultTemplateResolver() {
        TemplateResolver result = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        result.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/templates/");
        result.setSuffix(".html");
        result.setTemplateMode("LEGACYHTML5");
        result.setCacheable(false); // TODO Only for dev
        return result;
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine(TemplateResolver templateResolver) {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        Set<IDialect> dialects = new HashSet<>();
        dialects.add(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        templateEngine.setAdditionalDialects(dialects);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver(SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentViewResolver() throws Exception {
        ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean contentNegotiationManager = new ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean();
        contentNegotiationManager.addMediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        MappingJackson2JsonView defaultView = new MappingJackson2JsonView();
        defaultView.setExtractValueFromSingleKeyModel(true);

        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentViewResolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        contentViewResolver.setContentNegotiationManager(contentNegotiationManager.getObject());
        contentViewResolver.setDefaultViews(Arrays.<View>asList(defaultView));
        return contentViewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Security debug log

```
2015-07-14 14:05:31.352  INFO 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2015-07-14 14:05:31.352  INFO 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2015-07-14 14:05:31.387  INFO 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 35 ms
2015-07-14 14:05:31.460 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token']
2015-07-14 14:05:31.460 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/web/home'; against '/oauth/token'
2015-07-14 14:05:31.460 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/token_key']
2015-07-14 14:05:31.460 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/web/home'; against '/oauth/token_key'
2015-07-14 14:05:31.460 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/check_token']
2015-07-14 14:05:31.460 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/web/home'; against '/oauth/check_token'
2015-07-14 14:05:31.460 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2015-07-14 14:05:31.460 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfiguration$NotOAuthRequestMatcher@7d97df04
2015-07-14 14:05:31.461 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : matched
2015-07-14 14:05:31.462 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /web/home at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2015-07-14 14:05:31.462 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /web/home at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2015-07-14 14:05:31.463 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /web/home at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2015-07-14 14:05:31.463 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@63d700f9
2015-07-14 14:05:31.463 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /web/home at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2015-07-14 14:05:31.463 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/web/home'; against '/logout'
2015-07-14 14:05:31.464 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /web/home at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter'
2015-07-14 14:05:31.464 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor         : Token not found in headers. Trying request parameters.
2015-07-14 14:05:31.464 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.o.p.a.BearerTokenExtractor         : Token not found in request parameters.  Not an OAuth2 request.
2015-07-14 14:05:31.464 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] p.a.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter : No token in request, will continue chain.
2015-07-14 14:05:31.464 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /web/home at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2015-07-14 14:05:31.464 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /web/home at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2015-07-14 14:05:31.465 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /web/home at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2015-07-14 14:05:31.466 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2015-07-14 14:05:31.467 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /web/home at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2015-07-14 14:05:31.467 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Requested session ID 09564785AF0DDD41AB2645CEEE04E79E is invalid.
2015-07-14 14:05:31.467 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /web/home at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2015-07-14 14:05:31.467 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /web/home at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2015-07-14 14:05:31.467 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/web/home'; against '/api'
2015-07-14 14:05:31.467 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Public object - authentication not attempted
2015-07-14 14:05:31.468 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /web/home reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2015-07-14 14:05:31.622 ERROR 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "index": Error retrieving value for property "username" of authentication object of class org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken (index)
2015-07-14 14:05:31.624 DEBUG 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2015-07-14 14:05:31.626 ERROR 12373 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error retrieving value for property "username" of authentication object of class org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken (index)] with root cause
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring Boot you should remove your `SpringConfigurationInitializer` and use `SpringBootServletInitializer`. For example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

For details, refer to the [Spring Boot](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) reference.

Comment: Does it work when running as a Spring Boot app? Can you provide your complete stacktrace?

Comment: Added stacktrace link as it's too big for this post. I run in my IDE using the gradle bootRun definition.

Comment: After many attempts at refactoring the configuration I found that the problem was the class derived from GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration. As soon as I removed this it started working but now I have no security again.

Comment: Can you update your configuration? Perhaps if we can reproduce it we can fix it. Also what version of Spring Security and OAuth are you using?

Comment: Added configuration. I'm using Spring Security 4.0.1.RELEASE and Spring Security OAuth2 2.0.7.RELEASE